# Use both OpenIdConnect and JWT Bearer Token with Microsoft Identity Web ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to provide the ability for someone to access my API in a browser using OpenIdConnect or using the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow using a bearer token. This is similar functionality that I see with Microsoft D365 OData endpoints. I can access them via a browser but they require user authentication, or I can access them via an HTTP GET with a bearer token.

If I configure the Web API like this:

```
services.AddProtectedWebApi(this.Configuration).
AddSignIn(this.Configuration);
```

I can access the GET API from the browser and if I am not already authenticated it will prompt me for my credentials and authenticate me. However, if I attempt to access the same API from Postman with a bearer token it returns a web page for authentication.

If I configure the Web API like this:

```
services.AddProtectedWebApi(this.Configuration);
```

I get a 401 error in the browser but I am able to access the API from Postman with a bearer token.

I would like to be able to use the bearer token if it is provided and otherwise challenge for user credentials.

My Controller users `[Authorize]` and I am currently not using any validation in the GET action. I am letting the middleware do all the validation.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by adding the schemes to the `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller. I changed the attribute to `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` that will allow me to be authenticated in the browser (by logging into D365 or office) and will then authenticate me for the API. If I call the API from Postman with a bearer token it will also authenticate successfully.

I do see one strange behavior. If I am not already authenticated in the browser (or if I start an incognito session) I am no longer prompted for a my credentials and I receive a 401 result. However, if I decorate the controller with `[Authorize]` or `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme]` I will be prompted in the browser and authenticated succesfully but Postman will receive a login page rather than being authenticated by the bearer token.

I also noticed that `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider.GetRequestHandlerSchemesAsync()` always returns `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` as the request scheme. It is odd to me that a call from Postman which uses the `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` still returns `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` as the request scheme.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I've been investigating this exact same problem for the past week and have encountered the same 401 problem you've described in your update post. I think I may have encountered a breakthrough today.

Inspired by https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1469#issuecomment-399239254, I came up with the following:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddProtectedWebApi(
    options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.ForwardDefaultSelector = (context =>
        {
            var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToArray();
            if (authHeader.Length > 0 && authHeader[0].StartsWith("Bearer "))
            {
                return JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }

            return OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });
    },
    configureMicrosoftIdentityOptions: options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options),
    tokenDecryptionCertificate: certificate
);

services.AddSignIn(Configuration);
```

And then for my controllers, I've decorated them with the `[Authorize]` attribute and set the OpenIDConnect and JwtBearer authentication schemes via a class I've implemented that implements `IControllerModelConvention`, inspired by https://joonasw.net/view/apply-authz-by-default, but applying the schemes instead of policies (since that didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in .NET 7 app by setting `AddJwtBearer` explicitly:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        var conf = new MicrosoftIdentityOptions();
        builder.Configuration.GetSection(Constants.AzureAd).Bind(conf);
        
        opt.Audience = $"api://{conf.ClientId}";
        opt.Authority = $"{conf.Instance}{conf.TenantId}";
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);
```

Then the API controller needs to know the **scheme**:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
...
```